# Implement my own string comparison

Tags: java, string, comparison

I've been given this question of string comparison. I had to write a method to compare two strings without using java's built in string comparison methods. Also it suppose to be around 3 - 5 lines of code long. The method should return 0 for equal, 1 for string 'a' is bigger then string 'b', -1 for string 'a' is smaller then 'b'

Now, I know Java compares string based on the `int` value of each char so I tried to do this thing, which works but is definitely not 3-5 lines of code long:

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2){

    int result = 0;
    int count = 0; // The counter for the first string integer values sum
    int count2 = 0; // The counter for the second string integer values sum

    for(int c=0; c<s1.length(); c++){
        count = count +s1.charAt(c);
    }

    for (int c2=0; c2<s2.length(); c2++){
        count2 = count2 +s2.charAt(c2);
    }

    //***** some condition statement to check which is bigger and then return the result
```

Comment: The count is not useful for Strings longer than one character.  Why don't you compare each character in the String as String does?

Comment: Your algorithm is wrong: 'az' is smaller the 'ba', athough the sum of its chars is bigger.

Comment: Thank you friend, can suggest any other proper solution?

Comment: it is not a length comparison. The method should be able to determine which string is bigger based on lexicographically values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered doing a simple lexicographic comparison rather than comparing lengths (or whatever it is that you try to do, it's not particularly easy to tell):

```
for(int i=0; i<a.length() && i<b.length(); i++) {
    if(a.charAt(i) != b.charAt(i))
        return a.charAt(i) < b.charAt(i) ? -1 : 1;
}
return a.length() < b.length() ? -1 : a.length() == b.length() ? 0 : 1;
```

This is basically the same as what `java.lang.String`s do except it only uses public methods.

Comment: I will upvote for your solution for the part that I missed in mine `a.length() == b.length() ? 0` althought I found it really unfair that mine is downvoted while it's almost the same solution!

Answer (score 0):

Considering 2 `String` `a` and `b` a solution might be:

```
int comp = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < Math.min(a.length(), b.length()); i++) 
    if((comp = a.charAt(i) - b.charAt(i)) != 0)
        return comp;
return a.length() < b.length() ? -1 : a.length() == b.length() ? 0 : 1;
```

which calculates the difference of every `char` in the same position upto the smaller `String` length and if they are all `0` returns the smaller `String`.

Edit: I don't know the reason for the downvoting might be but anyway on a quick test it works as expected (and it's 5 lines long).

Comment: Can please explain the reason for downvoting?

Comment: Test your algorithm, and you'll see.

Comment: OK I think now is fixed

Answer (score 0):

I think this recursive approach might work for you:

```
public static int compare(String a, String b, int pos){
    if(a.charAt(pos) == b.charAt(pos) && pos >= a.length() && pos >= b.length())
        return 0;
    else if(a.charAt(pos) > b.charAt(pos))
        return 1;
    else if(a.charAt(pos) < b.charAt(pos))
        return -1;
    else {
        pos++;
        if(pos < a.length() && pos < b.length())
            return compare(a,b,pos);
        else if(pos < a.length() && pos >= b.length())
            return 1;
        else if(pos >= a.length() && pos < b.length())
            return -1;
        else return 0;
    }
}
```

You have to call the `compare` method on main with the variable `pos` at `0` like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a = "azzz";
    String b = "azz";

    System.out.println("" + compare(a,b,0));
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try. I tested it a bit and it seems to work. If it doesn't, then sorry. I've got much to learn.

So, my try is based on how Strings are treated in Java, i.e. they are immutable. Any String you create goes into a "Constant String Pool". When you make a new reference to a String that is already in the pool, the JVM makes that reference indicate to the String object that already exists in the pool. So I think it is clear that 2 identical String references are pointing to the exact same String object, even if they have been created separately. Based on this, my method returns 0 if the references are equal and does something else otherwise. Please excuse the return at the end, I know it's ugly, the program won't compile without. I also know(hope) it is unreachable. Here is the function(6 lines):

```
public int compare(String s1, String s2) {

    if (s1 == s2) return 0;
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(s1.length(), s2.length()); i++) {
            if (s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i)) return 1;
            else return -1;
        }
    }
    return -2;
}
```

Comment: `String s1 = "Hello"; String s2 = new String("Hello"); System.out.println(compare(s1, s2));` - I believe that would print -2, as though the Strings are identical, their references wouldn't be.

Comment: They don't - try it. Strings created with `new String("")` aren't immediately interned to the string pool.

Comment: It actually prints -1 on mine. A simpler test would be to do `System.out.println("Hello" == new String("Hello"));`. You'll see that it prints `false`, because they *don't* reference the same object.

Comment: You *could* manually call `.intern()` on each argument during the referential equality check (so `s1.intern() == s2.intern()`) and then that line would work properly for the example I gave as well.

Comment: doesn't intern() use equals() ?

Comment: `intern()` is a native method that's platform dependent. Vague answer, I know. It won't necessarily use an equivalent to `equals()` though - it could compare hash codes instead, or do something else entirely.

Comment: I did a little more playing around with your method - I can get it to return a `-2` if one of the arguments is the empty string. That's the route through that the compiler had found and was complaining about.

Answer (score -2):

This should work... (haven't compiled so not 100% sure).  I know it isn't < 5 lines but it should work correctly.  Can try to shorten it after that.

```
for(int i=0; i < s1.length(); i++)
{
    if(s2.length()-1 < i)
      return -1;
    if(s1.charAt(i) > s2.charAt(i))
      return -1;
    if(s1.charAt(i) < s2.charAt(i))
      return 1;
}
if(s2.length() > s1.length())
  return 1;
return 0;
```

Comment: Doesn't compile, and is wrong. The length doesn't tell anything about which is lexicographically smaller than the other one: 'aaaaaaa' is smaller than 'z'. The length is only relevant if the bigger string starts with the smaller string.

Comment: Misunderstood your question.  My apologies.

Comment: Still broken. `length` is a property of arrays, not Strings. You'd need `length()`. Either way, the point still remains that the OP *doesn't want a comparison based upon the length*.

Comment: This shouldn't compare anything on length.  The only times it does is if the same it has the same chars.  IE.  aaa is smaller than aaaa.

Comment: As I said, I didn't compile it... so there could be minor issues like missing parenthesis.  Thanks for the suggestion though.  Answer edited to add them.

Comment: The *very first thing* that this method does after going into the loop is compare the length of the second String to `i`, and straight up returns a `1` if it's smaller. **That is a length comparison**. In the case of the first condition being false, you then only ever compare the first characters of each string rather than the entire string, so the result will only be accurate for strings of length `1`.

Comment: Ok but it only returns it if it is smaller AFTER looping through multiple times.

Take the example AAA v AAB.  It will loop through all 3 times right?  And eventually see that AAA comes before AAB.  Now take AAA v AA.  It will loop through twice and then see that AAA is bigger than AA.  That is what that comparison is for.

Comment: Ok.  I compiled the code.  I had the return statements turned around.  However I guarantee that this solution works.

Comment: AAABA vs AABAA. These are equal, but not according to your method. How about ACC vs ADZ? ADZ is clearly the larger string, but your method thinks ACC is larger.

Comment: I kinda feel better now knowing It's not as easy as it sounds for others too.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the OP but he said in his comments that "The method should be able to determine which string is bigger based on lexicographically values."  If I am not mistaken lexicographical order is alphabetical.  No?

Comment: (a,b) ≤ (a′,b′) if and only if a < a′ or (a = a′ and b ≤ b′).

Comment: Ok.  By that logic, isn't my solution correct?  I suppose my question is.  Does the order of the characters matter?  Is it supposed to be alphabetical (or dictionary) order?  Or is it the SUM of all the chars?

Comment: Well in it's current state this does seem to work if the comparison should purely be based on lexicographical order, but doesn't if the desired comparison is between the sum of the values of each character in the two Strings. I think @Yosi199 needs to clarify exactly under which criteria one string is bigger than the other. In your ideal implementation, what should be the outcome of comparing AB with BA?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for not being clear. All in all this method should be rather identical in functionality to the native string.compareTO().
As if I would've Overriden it

Comment: Ah ok.  Then no, this solution would not work.  It only works for lexicographical order.

Comment: Ah ok. Then no, this solution would not work. It only works for _what the OP actually asked_.